# In app battery usage

Tags: android, performance, battery

Is there any way to determine what is using power in an app? From what I have found, the most granular I can get is how much power an app itself is using. I want to know what I can do to make my app more efficient in the most empirical way possible as it is easy to justify a change when there are numbers to back it up.

Comment: Programatically, I don't think so.  Logically, yes.  Anything that causes it to use hardware that could otherwise be idle will cause it to use battery.  That means GPS, internet, wakelocks, etc.  If you must use these, try to batch them so that you only need to keep them on a brief time, and that they can go back to sleep between uses.

Comment: That would be great if there is a way to find that out, but according to the [BatteryManager page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) it doesn't seem like something like that would be possible. Though the screen is what always consumes the most power. Maybe turning on auto brightness in `onCreate` would help...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to determine what is using power in an app?

You can buy a Qualcomm MDP device and use Trepn to get fairly accurate and detailed power analysis of your app. However, an MDP is expensive.

Otherwise, there is little you can do, simply because current Android production hardware is not instrumented to try to collect this level of information. Even the Battery screen in Settings is mostly just an educated guess.